# Unable to locate dependency 'class library project(s)'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, docker, ubuntu-14.04, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created ASP.NET Core webAPI project with following folder structure.

/src

- /WebApiProject

  - Dockerfile
- /DomainProject
- /CoreProject

WebApiProject has dependency of `DomainProject` and `CoreProject`. Everything is working fine with `dnu restore` dependencies of `DomainProject` and `CoreProject` are resolved because both are peer folders. Also I am able to run my webApi by executing dnx web command.

Now, I am trying to create docker image in my Ubuntu machine and for that I am referring below link:
https://blogs.infosupport.com/build-deploy-test-aspnetcore-docker-linux-tfs2015/

but when I try to create docker image i am getting below error message:

**Errors in /app/project.json**

"Unable to locate dependency **DomainProject** >= 1.0.0.*

"Unable to locate dependency **CoreProject** >= 1.0.0.*

Can someone help me to resolve this issue ?
`dnu restore` is able resolve the dependency but during docker image create these dependency doesn't resolved.

### Below is the my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr

RUN printf "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get install -qqy sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5001/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]
```

Comment: I run into this very same problem. This SO answer helped me sort it out.     http://stackoverflow.com/a/30911720/1694701

Comment: @zaidorx, thanks provided answer in above SO helped me also and it is working like a charm!