# How to host asp.net core wep api inside docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently started learning `docker`, But I am facing issues while hosting a simple `asp.net core web api` boiler plate app created using `Visual Studio Code` inside a `docker` windows container.

I have set `Docker Fie` in project and run `docker build --tag helloapi .`

But when I run `docker run -p 9000:80 helloapi` I get bellow error:

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
>   specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was
>   not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         \
>     - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.1.1'.

I have tried many tutorials [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grbc8mevLRc) [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hy7lD9Mngw) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880135/asp-net-5-docker-build-with-multi-projects-solution).

I have a tried different docker images for asp.net core [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/) [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile).

**dotnet core version:**

```
 dotnet --info

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
  Version:   2.1.402

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.402 

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4
```

**helloapi.csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Docker File:**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloApi.dll"]
```

[image]

**Note:** I am not able to Switch to `Linux Container` because docker is showing some run time error, So I am using `Windows Container` and also `IIS Server` is not enabled in Turn windows features.

I am not able to figure out what wrong am  I doing ?

Can anyone guide me the correct way to host `api` using `docker` in windows container.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your Dockerfile as well?

Comment: Have you run docker build first?

Comment: @SimplyGed , I have updated, Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund , Its is obvious and I ran it, I have updated the the info in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the generated dockerfile form vs don't reference the `dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime` and `dotnet:2.1-sdk`.

Try to these steps

Add below Dockerfile to your solution folder

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /build
COPY . /build

#Restore
RUN dotnet restore ./HelloApi.sln

RUN dotnet publish ./HelloApi/ -o /publish --configuration Release

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /publish/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Build it

`docker build -t app1 .`

Run it

`docker run -p 8080:80 --name appcontainer1 app1`

Test it

Browse to *http://localhost:8080*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tutorials you have been following are all for .NET Core 2.0 but your project is using .NET Core 2.1.

As you (probably) know, the first line in the `Dockerfile` defines what image to run your application on. In your case you `microsoft/aspnetcore`. If you take a look at the [Docker Hub page for the microsoft/aspnetcore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/) image you will see it says:

> Latest images for 2.1 and newer are now available on microsoft/dotnet. See this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/blob/master/2.1) for more details about migrating to 2.1.

Clicking on that link takes you to the Docker Hub page for the [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) image, which supports .NET Core 2.1.

So, as stated in another answer, you need to change your `Dockerfile` to reference a different image that has the .NET Core 2.1 runtime installed.
You could just change the first line to:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
```

which could use an image that has the .NET Core 2.1 SDK installed, but that image would be overkill if you are planning to deploy the image to production.

Current practice is to use multi-stage Dockerfiles to perform the build, test and publish steps inside the container. You can read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/docker/building-net-docker-images). This allows you to use a different image base to build and test your application but only use the smaller runtime image for the final production image.

Take a look at some of the [.NET Core Docker Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/README.md) to see how to do this.

Just be mindful when you are looking for tutorials that they use the newer .NET Core 2.1 as the base image, or ensure you create any applications using the same .NET Core version as the tutorial.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate for the detailed info. I will try this and let you know later.

Answer (score 1):

> Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
COPY ./SampleWebApi.csproj /SampleWebApi/
RUN dotnet restore ./SampleWebApi/SampleWebApi.csproj
COPY . ./SampleWebApi/
WORKDIR /SampleWebApi/
RUN dotnet build "SampleWebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleWebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleWebApi.dll"]
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    sample-web-api:
        build: SampleWebApi/
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "7000:80"
```

> Run the below command

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

[Sample web API code along with Dockerfile on Github](https://github.com/narottamgoyal/DotNetCore.WebApi.On.Docker)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully hosted dotnet core 2.1 WebAPI applications in docker using Kestrel web-server with the [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) image and tags of *2.1-sdk* and *dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime* for build and runtime respectively in multi-stage build e.g.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using `windows container` , Could you share your working `DockerFile` ?